# Fill color for each area based on x and y start, end values

Tags: highcharts

I want something like the below screenshot in Highcharts with dateaxis (x-axis), filling colors in the series based on x, y axis start and end values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried zones? This is an option available from the API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.zones